# How to set a python property in __init__

Tags: python

I have a class with an attribute I wish to turn into a `property`, but this attribute is set within `__init__`. Not sure how this should be done. Without setting the property in `__init__` this is easy and works well

```
import datetime

class STransaction(object):
    """A statement transaction"""
    def __init__(self):
        self._date = None

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self._date

    @date.setter
    def date(self, value):
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%d-%b-%y")
        self._date = d

st = STransaction()
st.date = "20-Jan-10"
```

But once initialization needs to occur in `__init__` it gets more complicated and I am not sure of the correct course of action.

```
class STransaction(object):
    """A statement transaction"""
    def __init__(self, date):
        self._date = None
```

Strangely to me, the following seems to work but smells very bad.

```
class STransaction(object):
    """A statement transaction"""
    def __init__(self, date):
        self._date = None
        self.date = date

    @property
    def date(self):
        return self._date

    @date.setter
    def date(self, value):
        d = datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%d-%b-%y")
        self._date = d
```

What is the correct way to go about setting properties in `__init__`?

Comment: In general, is there any reason to set `self._date = None` before updating the property since it will be immediately overwritten with the new value?

Comment: No. It only makes sense if the second line is absent to prevent the getter being called with no attribute "_date" set

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I do not see any real problem with your code. In `__init__`, the class is fully created and thus the properties accessible.

Comment: Ok, so perhaps I am looking at this the wrong way. At the point of __init__ is the property already created so my call to self.date is accessing via the property is the same way that my call to st.date is?

Comment: Yes, exactly (why does Stackoverflow dislike short, to-the-point messages? - it refused to post just "Yes, exactly").

Comment: +1 Perfectly right. I would add that the self._date = None in __init__ is really useless in  this code (You can in some cases put the initialization of properties hidden variables in the getter using RAII ( `if not hasattr(self,_smth): do initialization...`)

Answer (score 10):

```
class STransaction(object):
    """A statement transaction"""
    def __init__(self, date):
        self._date = None #1
        self.date = date  #2
```

If you want to set the proxy field `self._date` without executing of your setter use the #1 line. If you would like to execute the setter at startup too use the #2. Both ways are correct, it's just a matter of what do you want to do.

Comment: Why would you want to set `_date` to `None` when init clearly is called with some particular `date`? You should store the correct value, hence #1 is not viable.