# Python property returning property object

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a class like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar = property(self.get_bar)

    def get_bar(self):
        return "bar"

print Foo().bar  #this prints <property object at 0x0051CB40>
```

I've seen [How do Python properties work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6193556/how-do-python-properties-work), [How to set a python property in __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941919/how-to-set-a-python-property-in-init?rq=1), but they all use the decorator method, which i don't because i want a different name. And I need access to `self`

How do i get the property to behave?

Comment: Why would you like to use different name? Is there a reasonable reason?

Comment: Have you tried using property as a decorator or with a docstring?

Comment: A quick solution will be to call `__get__` on `bar` explicitly: `f = Foo();f.bar.__get__(f, type(f))`

Comment: (since this is the first web hit I found for my problem:) One other reason a property object can be returned instead of the property (even if the correct way of writing the property is used) is if the class is not instantiated into an object:  print(Foo.bar) instead of print(Foo().bar)

Comment: @MichaelScottCuthbert I think you should add this as an alternative answer, despite not being directly related with the question. I had this problem and your comment saved me! Thank you!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You need to make a minor change:

```
class Foo(object):

    def get_bar(self):
        return "bar"

    bar = property(get_bar)

print Foo().bar # prints bar
```

The property needs to be an attribute of the class, not the instance; that's how the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) protocol works.

Comment: I was defining the property before the function. All okay now.

Comment: @gcq Now, try and set the value of `bar`.

Comment: Why does the output of property work differently if it's `bar = property()` at the top level vs. `self.bar = property()` within `__init__`?

Comment: @EL_DON because the property needs to be an attribute of the *class*, not the *instance*; that's how the [descriptor](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) protocol works.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks. Maybe put that in the answer?

Answer (score 9):

The object is not instantiated.

```
class Foo(object):
  def get_bar(self):
    return "bar"

bar = Foo()
print(bar.get_bar)
```

Comment: This was the correct answer for me. I had done `Foo.get_bar` rather than `Foo().get_bar`. E.g., the object was not instantiated.

Comment: Lol, it was my case too. After ~30 minutes of debbugging I found some place deep in the code where the property was read from class, not instance...

Answer (score 8):

You can do it like this

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__bar = None

    def get_bar(self):
        return self.__bar

    def set_bar(self, value):
        self.__bar = value

    bar = property(get_bar, set_bar)

foo = Foo()
print foo.bar    # None
foo.bar = 1
print foo.bar    # 1
```

Answer (score 7):

You can also do it like shown [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self._bar

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value

    @bar.deleter
    def bar(self):
        self._bar = None # for instance
```

which is equivalent to:

```
class Also_Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._bar = None

    def get_bar(self):
        return self._bar

    def set_bar(self, value):
        self._bar = value

    def del_bar(self):
        self._bar = None # for instance

    bar = property(fget=get_bar, fset=set_bar, fdel=del_bar, doc=None)
```

**BUT** without polluting the class namespace with `get` and `set` methods for each attribute.

You retain external direct access to the variable by using `._bar` instead of `.bar`.

Answer (score 0):

My use case required defining `bar` as a property only under certain conditions, so I took [jonrsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe)'s advice and moved the definition into `__new__` instead:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __new__(cls):
        cls.bar = property(cls.get_bar)
        return super(Foo, cls).__new__(cls)

    def get_bar(self):
        return "bar"

print(Foo().bar)  #this prints "bar"
```

However, nothing was gained by this "cleverness". Once the condition was met, the class contained the property. I might as well have defined it as jonrsharpe did.

Answer (score 0):

Do the following if you want to do within **init**()

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        type(self).bar = property(self.get_bar)

    def get_bar(self):
       return "bar"
```

The property method is basically similar to property decoration, it tells python to define a property.

And then we assign this to "bar" property of the type. This needs to be at the type level because you are defining the property for the class, so it is static, not a specific instance.

get_bar is your usual getter where you use the decorator.

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including a detailed explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.