# Class property returning property object

Tags: python, python-3.x, properties, metaprogramming

Before this is flagged as a duplicate, I know this [question has been answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21812092/python-property-returning-property-object) before, but the solutions provided there don't seem to apply to my case. I'm trying to programmatically set class properties. I know I can use `property` for that, so I thought about doing this:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        def getx(): return self._x
        def setx(y): self._x = y
        self.x = property(fget=getx, fset=setx)
```

However, when I run this interactively, I get:

```
>>> f = Foo(42)
>>> f.x
<property object at 0x0000000>
>>> f._x
42
>>> f.x = 1
>>> f.x
1
```

Is there any way to solve this?

*Edit:*

I feel I may have left out too much, so here's what I am actually trying to reach. I have a class with a class variable called `config`, which contains configuration values to set as properties. The class should be subclassed to implement the `config` variable:

```
class _Base:
    config = ()

    def __init__(self, obj, **kwargs):
        self._obj = obj()
        for kwarg in kwargs:
            # Whatever magic happens here to make these properties

# Sample implementation
class Bar(_Base):
     config = (
         "x",
         "y"
     )

     def __init__(self, obj, x, y):
         super().__init__(obj, x=x, y=y)
```

Which now allows for manipulation:

```
>>> b = Bar(x=3, y=4)
>>> b.x
3
>>> # Etc.
```

I'm trying to keep this as DRY as possible because I have to subclass `_Base` a lot.

Comment: You're not setting it on the class, you're setting it on the object. Descriptors don't work like that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`property` objects are [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html), and descriptors are only invoked when defined on the class or metaclass. You can't put them directly on an instance; the `__getattribute__` implementation for classes simply don't invoke the binding behaviour needed.

You need to put the property on the class, not on each instance:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x

    @property
    def x(self): return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, y): self._x = y
```

If you have to have a property that only works on some instances, you'll have to alter your getter and setter methods to vary behaviour (like raise an `AttributeError` for when the state of the instance is such that the attribute should 'not exist').

```
class Bar:
    def __init__(self, has_x_attribute=False):
        self._has_x_attribute = has_x_attribute
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        if not self._has_x_attribute:
            raise AttributeError('x')
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, y):
        if not self._has_x_attribute:
            raise AttributeError('x')
        self._x = y
```

The `property` object still exists and is bound, but behaves as if the attribute does not exist when a flag is set to false.

Comment: I just now realized how stupid my attempt was. Thanks.