# Setting a Python property from __init__()

Tags: python

I want to define a class that ensures some constraints when a property is set/modified. Furthermore, I want to be able to set the property value on construction, with the same constraints. Simplified example:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, attrval):
        self.myattr = attrval
    
    @property
    def myattr(self):
        return self._myattr

    @myattr.setter
    def myattr(self, value):
        if value is None:
            raise ValueError("Attribute value of None is not allowed!")
        self._myattr = value
```

I'm calling the property setter right from `__init__()`, so the property is the only place where `self._myattr` is accessed directly. Are there any problems or caveats in using a property like this (like a missing or invalid creation of `_myattr`)? Maybe when (multiple) inheritance comes in? Is there a PEP or some other "official" statement about how to properly initialize properties from `__init__()`?

Most property examples I found do not use the property setter from the constructor. In [How to set a python property in __init__](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3941919/how-to-set-a-python-property-in-init), the underlying attribute gets created explicitly before setting the property. Some people think that each single attribute must be explicitly initialized in `__init__()`, that's why my code example feels a bit odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There won't be any problems. Use what works for you.

One thing to keep in mind is that setting the attribute using the `setter` runs the validation you've set up. Setting the attribute directly in the `__init__` won't have that validation executed. This would make the `setter` version more slower, but safer as per disallowing certain values.