# Lock ConfigParser in read-only mode

Tags: python, readonly, configparser

Is there an attribute to lock a `ConfigParser` object in read-inly mode ?

I'm using a project-wide global `ConfigParser` object and I want to prevent the code from modifying the object. I could easily override `ConfigParser.set(section,option,value)` to raise an error if the method is called, but I'm wondering if I haven't overlooked a simpler solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a generic solution to this problem (using this fantastic snippet written by Felix Kling here : [How to create a constant in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2682745/creating-constant-in-python) ). 
My aim is to simplify the debugger's job, using a bit of defensive programming, not to prevent any malicious access of the class.

Moreover, it's kind of hackish : constant members and private/protected access are does get along well with Python's philosophy ('explicit better than implicit' , ...).

---

### Phase 1 : Block setters

First, we have to block any setters from ConfigParse : easy peasy, we just have to override `set(self, section, option, value)` :

```
def set(self, section, option, value):
    raise SyntaxError("No modification authorized")
```

---

### Phase 2 : Block Members

This part is a bit more problematic : in order to control the setter on a constant member, we have to disguise a method as a member using the `@property` decorator. The `@constant` decorator is simply a modified `@property` decorator :

```
# Constant decorator
def constant(f):
    def fset(self, value):
        raise SyntaxError("Don't touch that !")
    def fget(self):
        return f(self)
    return property(fget, fset)

# Config Class. Notice the object name in the type of class FixedConfig has to derived from
# ( Python 2.xx and new-style class purpose) 
# (see more here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/598077/why-does-foo-setter-in-python-not-work-for-me )

class FixedConfig( object, ConfigParser):
    def __init__(self):
        ConfigParser.__init__()
        self.read("filepath to config file")

    def set(self, section, option, value):
        raise SyntaxError("No modification authorized")

    #fake DNS service : map domain names to IP
    @constant
    def DNS(self):
        return { self.get("domain names", IP) : IP  \ 
                  for IP in self.options("domain names") )
```

---

### Phase 3 : Block Methods

Finally, you have to prevent class methods from be rewritten ( the magic of Python's monkey patching ). Those kind of modification are not usual, but can happen (especially when dealing with dependency inversion). In our case, we don't want `FixedConfig.set` to be rewritten :

```
config = FixedConfig()
print config.get("domain names", "127.0.0.1")
#>> 'localhost'
config.set = super(FixedConfig,self).set  # swap FixedConfig.set with ConfigParser.set
config.set("domain names", "127.0.0.1", "CommandAndControl") 
print config.get("domain names", "127.0.0.1")
#>> 'CommandAndControl'
```

To prevent it, you just have to decorate the `set` method with `@constant`.

---

Again, it does not stop a malicious person from rewritten the constant decorator and override the set property ( I don't thnink we can have this kind of protection in Python anyway) but still is much easier to track the call to the constant decorator rather than the calls to a config member throughout your project.