# Why is my python 2.7 getter acting like a setter?

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, setter, getter

For some reason I have a class with a python getter acting like a setter...I have no idea why this is happening. If anyone could help me that would be much appriciated. :) This is my code

```
class Testclass():
    def __init__(self):
        self._testvar = None

    @property
    def testvar(self):
        return self._testvar

    @testvar.setter
    def testvar(self, value):
        assert False

testObj = Testclass()
testObj.testvar = "test"
print (testObj.testvar)
```

for some reason when I run the program it prints "test" but I am wanting it to print "None" or maybe even throw an error when I use

```
testobj.testvar = "test"
```

Comment: You didn't define a setter. You're just overriding your property by setting it to `"test"`. If you want to define a setter, then you need to define a function decorated with `@testvar.setter`. And make sure your class [inherits from `object`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/598077/why-does-foo-setter-in-python-not-work-for-me).

Comment: but even when I use

`
@testvar.setter
    def testvar(self, value):
        assert False
`

it does the same thing

Comment: Read the link I provided, you most likely didn't inherit `object`.

Comment: Aaah no it didn't lol I didn't realize I had to inherit from object...ty. :) I wish this was an actual answer I would mark it as the solution. lol

Comment: Just follow the link of the duplicate and upvote the accepted answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `object` as parent class.

```
class Testclass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._testvar = None

    @property
    def testvar(self):
        return self._testvar

    @testvar.setter
    def testvar(self, value):
        self._testvar = value

testObj = Testclass()
print(testObj.testvar)
testObj.testvar = "test"
print(testObj.testvar)

>>> None
>>> test
```

Answer (score 0):

You are dynamically creating a new member variable, called `testvar`, and adding it to your class, which then overrides your property name.

To verify this, you can change the assignment to e.g.

```
testObj.testvar2 = "test"
```

and everything will work as you expect, showing `None` as the value for testvar.

Comment: ok but even when I use a `@testvar.setter` decorator it still does the same thing...I updated my op to show the changes I made

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure that the way python works, when you do:

```
testobj.testvar = "test"
```

what you are actually doing is replacing the method Testclass.testvar() with the string "test".   Essentially you are stomping on your function.  Maybe you meant to do

```
testobj._testvar = "test"
```

Comment: Well, I am trying to avoid accessing the member variables directly outside of the class and instead using getters and setters so that I can access them safely. I always thought the @property decorator was used to turn a function into a getter method.

Comment: Calling it a getter doesn't prevent  you from coming along later and replacing it, which is what you've done here.