# RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

when I tried to run this code , I got an error

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name= name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self.name

    @name.setter
    def name(self,name):
         print(self.name)

pizza = Pizza(["cheese", "tomato"])
```

the error :

> RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

But when I changed the code by making (name) private ,it works fine !

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name= name

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self,name):
        print(self.name)
pizza = Pizza(["cheese", "tomato"])
```

why I got an error at first , and why it fixed when I make (name) private ?

Comment: `return self.name` - so to compute self.name, I return self.name. How do I compute that? I have to return self.name. I do that by returning self.name, and I have to return self.name to do that... the `return self.name` inside the `name` getter doesn't automagically bypass the property.

Comment: I get it ,, put an answer to give you the best answer

Comment: Python has no concept of "private" by the way

Comment: that is true ,,

Comment: This answer should help. http://stackoverflow.com/a/28464787/2308683

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Coming from other languages, its hard to grasp that python doesn't need getters and setters (unless you decide to name the instance variables differently).

For example, you can access that "property" directly since there isn't really the concept of pure encapsulation.

```
class Pizza:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

pizza = Pizza(["cheese", "tomato"])
print(pizza.name)  # ["cheese", "tomato"]
pizza.name = "garlic"
print(pizza.name)  # garlic
```

Comment: I have to get back to java