# Create Class of Lists in Python

Tags: python, oop, data-structures, subclass

I have to extract patient information from a bunch of XML files for further data analysis.

I have multiple **Patients** that can have multiple **Diseases** . For each Diseases there may or may not have been a **Treatment** or several. Each Treatment may or may not have **TreatmentDetails**. The TreatmentDetails are often duplicated in files (ie. files with different names, but the same TreatmentDetails for a Diseases or just a small change).

I think that a data structure of the type `Patient[i].Disease[j].Treatment[k]` might be useful for this problem. Unfortunately, I am not very good with Classes or OOP.

How can I achieve this type of data structure `Patient[i].Disease[j].Treatment[k]`?

Below is my code:

```
class PatientClass(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.patient = []

    def addPatient(self, PatientID, casVersion):
        self.patient.append((False, PatientID, casVersion))

    def patient_count(self):
        return(len(self.patient))

    def printPatient(self):
        print(self.patient)

    def printpatientN(self,n):
        print(self.patient[n])

    def __str__(self,n):
        return(self.patient[n])

class Disease(PatientClass):

    def __init__(self):
        PatientClass.__init__(self)
        self.disease = []

    def addDisease(self, datetime_Start, datetime_End):
        self.disease.append((False, datetime_Start, datetime_End))


    def printDiseaseN(self,n):
        print(self.disease[n])

    def __str__(self,n):
        return "%s has disease %s" % (self.patient[n], self.disease[n])
```

Comment: you definitely DON'T need inheritance

Comment: @AntiMatter is correct. Take a look at the [is-a vs has-a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2218937/has-a-is-a-terminology-in-object-oriented-language) distinction

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the builtin Python `dict` and/or `list` machinery and use very simple classes to structure your data. Below is an example of storing `Patient` objects. They are extended dicts - I choose dicts because that makes a good fit for records where you are free to add the fields you want at anytime, as new keys). I also use a standard dict to store `Patient` objects, using their record id as the key to store and retrieve Patient objects from the container `patients` dict.

The simple classes shown extend `UserDict` (the proper way to inherit from `dict`), with the "has-a list of" concept for the patient diseases and treatments.

An example of usage is shown, you can see that a lot of builtin useful behaviour is available via inheritance.

You can use this structure for your data or adapt it to your taste and needs (example: you may want to define an even simpler acess to some attributes by using properties, to write `.name` instead of `['name']`, 
see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43410484/7857466) for a brief explanation, or you might extend the classes in other ways).

`super().__init(...)` is just preserving the default initialization of the classes while adding more attributes, otherwise they won't function properly because they would override the defaults. `Treatment` doesn't need it because it does not redefine `__init__` (yet)

```
from collections import UserDict
# see also UserList, UserString

class Treatment(UserDict):
    pass

class Disease(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.treatments = []


class Patient(UserDict):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.diseases = []

patients = dict()

p1 = patients['0001'] = Patient(name='Eric', surname='Idle')

d1 = Disease(name='Eating too much')
t1 = Treatment(title='Radical Therapy', description='Mint pill after lunch.')
d1.treatments.append(t1)

d2 = Disease(name='Cannot Control the Legs Syndrome')
t2 = Treatment(title='Conservative Approach', description='Have a seat.')
d2.treatments.append(t2)

p1.diseases.extend([d1,d2])

for pid in patients:
    print()
    print('PID:{} {} {}'.format(pid, patients[pid]['name'],\
           patients[pid]['surname']))
    print(50*'-')
    for disease in patients[pid].diseases:
        print()
        print('Disease: {}'.format(disease['name']))
        for treatment in disease.treatments:
            print('Treatment: {}'.format(treatment['title']))
            print('\t\t{}'.format(treatment['description']))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this simple implementation of 'has-a' paradigm:

```
    class Patient:

        def __init__(self, patientID, casVersion):
            self.patientID = patientID
            self.casVersion = casVersion
            self.disease = []

        def addDisease(self, disease):
            self.disease.append(disease)
            return self

        def __str__(self):
            return "<Patient: %s, casVer: %s, disease: %s>" % (self.patientID, self.casVersion, " ".join([str(d) for d in self.disease]))

    class Disease:

        def __init__(self, datetimeStart, datetimeEnd):
            self.datetimeStart = datetimeStart
            self.datetimeEnd = datetimeEnd
            self.treatment = []

        def __str__(self):
            return "<Disease: start: %s, end: %s, treatment: %s>" % (self.datetimeStart, self.datetimeEnd, " ".join([str(t) for t in self.treatment]))


# usage
print Patient("TheFirst", "Cas").addDisease(Disease("yesterday", "today"))
```